# Query total rewards per validator

Tags: staking, validators

Sites like [beaconcha.in](https://beaconcha.in/) are listing the total rewards per validator (split into EL and CL values). How can I query this information on-chain using something like [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js) or maybe [ethdo](https://github.com/wealdtech/ethdo)?